# Correspondence beween countable ordinals and monotone functions

Tags: set-theory

I have a curiosity: is it true that every countable ordinal $\lambda$, there is a monotone function $F : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, whose closure ordinal is $\lambda$?

I've been trying to prove this on my own but no luck. I'm starting to think it might be false.

Here $\mathcal{P}(X)$ means the power set of the set $X$. Also, monotone and closure ordinal represent the usual definitions.

Comment: The power set is a common concept taught at the undergraduate level, but what is a "closure ordinal"?

Comment: @Henning: See the first two paragraphs of Section $2$ of [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183535523) for the definitions that I think Danx is using.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks, that was clearer than what I could google up immediately.

Answer (score 2):

If "closure ordinal" means what Brian M. Scott suggested in his comment, you should be able to take $\Gamma:\mathcal P(\lambda)\to\mathcal P(\lambda)$ defined by
$$ \Gamma(A)=\begin{cases} A\cup\{\min(\lambda\setminus A)\} &  \text{when }A\ne \lambda \\ A & \text{when } A =\lambda \end{cases} $$

Then, in the notation of Brian's reference, $\Gamma^\alpha = \alpha$ for all $\alpha\le\lambda$, and the closure ordinal of $\Gamma$ is exactly $\lambda$.

Since $\lambda$ is assumed countable, you can cojugate $\Gamma$ with the assumed bijection between $\lambda$ and $\mathbb N$ to get a $F:\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\to\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ with the same structure as $\Gamma$, and therefore the same closure ordinal.